# how do i run commandlink with repeat tag

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this VF page below.This is a product page where a list of products are displayed, I was hoping to run it with apex:repeat tag,but the thing is when i try to use var.method in command link and var.prodpic in image tag then i get error that these named methods are not found, there are no methods but the values these contain are the method names.
How do I make it work, any idea anyone.any help is appreciated.P.S.- Inventory_c is the custom object where the value for method and product pic is contained.

```
<apex:page controller="productslistpage" showHeader="false">
  <Apex:form >
        <br/><p style="font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;"> Products available today </p><br/>

       <apex:repeat value="{!Prodlist}" var="prod">

           <apex:CommandLink action="{!invent.ButtonName__c}" >
              <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource[prod.prodpic__c])" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>prod.name(Gray)</h3> 
            </apex:commandlink>
            <p>prod.price--c</p>
```

Controller

```
public Class productslistpage{

    public list<inventory__c> prodlist{get; set;} 
    public string PID{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public string usermode{get; set;}

public productslistpage(){

    this.name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name');
    this.usermode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('usermode');
    prodlist = [Select ButtonName__c,Name, Price__c, Stocks__c,productid__c from Inventory__c];
}     

      PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/testprodpage');
public pagereference prod1button(){


      PID = '10004';    

      pg.getParameters().put('PID', PID);
      return pg; 
     }



}
```

Comment: Try not using the *var* keyword, instead use some different word in `var="var" ` as `var = "some_other_string"`

Comment: yup, usually it is not like that, i just wanted something for the question post, thanks for the info.

Comment: Is your question solved now?

Comment: Nope,in the code it is Invent, it didn't work, same error

Comment: does the repeat value has a collection or object name? I right now have stated object name, is that wrong, should i just be using the list variable that i am using in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apex:commandLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) documentation explains that the `action` attribute must reference a controller method not an SObject data field. See e.g. [Passing Parameters with a CommandLink](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/03/passing-parameters-with-a-commandlink/) for how to arrange that and still pass a value.

On the image reference, if `prodpic__c` holds the name of a static resource this [dynamic reference to a static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_resource.htm) pattern is the sort of code you need:

```
<apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource[var.prodpic__c])"/>
```

Comment: thanks Keith, umm i have updated the post, Can you please check. the image still doesn't work.

Comment: @Niknit Best you look at the "dynamic reference..." post I linked to for more information.